# MySQL Install the log,data and other files

Tags: mysql

Can you advise on installing the log,data and other files for MySQL?
I am actually a MSSQL Server DBA and have no ideas about the MySQL.

Comment: You should try this question over at http://www.serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Comment: +1. Read the manual, google some tutorials, then ask questions.